# i have confusion in concept of classes and objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object

i have confusion in concept of classes and objects in Java
i did the following code but i'm not sure if it right!!! 
So How can i test it and invoking this class in the main class?

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class Pizza {
  public String pizzasize;
  public int cheese;
  public  int pepperoni;
  public Pizza (String pizzasize1,int cheese1,int pepperoni1){
  pizzasize= pizzasize1;
  cheese=cheese1;
  pepperoni=pepperoni1;
 }
```

this method chick pizza size then declaring and assign pizza cost

```
  public void setPizza(String pizzasize1){
     switch(pizzasize1)
  {
      case "S":
      case "s":   
      {
   int  pc=10;break;
      }
      case "M":
      case "m":   
      {
   int  pc=12;break;
      }
      case "L":
      case "l":   
      {
   int  pc=14;break;
      }
      default:System.out.print("Wrong");
  }//switch
   pizzasize= pizzasize1;
  }
```

..

```
 public void setPizza(int cheese1,int pepperoni1){
   cheese=cheese1;
  pepperoni=pepperoni1;
  }

 public String getPizza(){
 return  pizzasize;
 }
 public int getPizza1(){
 return  cheese;
 }
public int getPizza2(){
return  pepperoni;
}

public void calcCost (int pc){
    double totalCost = pc+(cheese+pepperoni) *2;       
}
```

finally this method for sample output

```
public void getDiscriptions(String pizzasize,int cheese,int pepperoni,double totalCost){
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("place order");
System.out.println("size: L,M,s");
pizzasize=sc.next();
System.out.println("cheese: ");
cheese=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("pepperoni: ");
pepperoni=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("your order placed is/nlarge pizza with"+cheese+"cheese,"
 +pepperoni+"pepperoni,/ntotal cost is"+totalCost);
}

}//
```

Comment: what's your confusion about classes and objects?

Comment: Title of your post is "...confusion about classes and objects," but the only question seems to be "how can I test it."  In order to test it, you have to be able to describe conditions under which the program operates, and you have to be able to describe what the program is supposed to do under those conditions.  The rest is easy:  Run the program and see whether it does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Just add the main metodo in the class and the program will start from there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: @PetterFriberg its valid if you are using using java 7

Comment: Thanks you are right still used to 1.4 ; ), will delete my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you are Automobile Engineer and you get a contract to built new model car then what will you do to built car ??

I think, first you will gather information about:

`New brand name`, `Size`, `Shape`, `Weight`, `Color` etc.
`Speed`, `Acceleration`, `Rotation` etc.

After that you will start to design the blueprint of the car. The blueprint only shows how it works and how it looks. But you never able to feel it in realistic world with that blueprint.

To feel the car you have to built it with same feature as mentioned in blueprint. And only after that you can touch it, open the door, ride it, press brake and accelerator. With the same blueprint you can built car in any number as much as you want.

In OOP, `Class` is same as blueprint of car. It only shows you what car knows like: `color`, `size`, `weight`, `height`, `speed` and these are called attributes. It only tells you how car behaves like: it `runs`, it `stops`, it `rotates`, etc and these are called methods. Class doesn't exist in real world it's virtual.

```
class Car_Real {

    String brand_name;
    String color;
    float weight;
    float height;

    void runs() {
        System.out.println("Engine starts");
    }

    void accelerates() {    
        System.out.println("Speed goes on increasing");    
    }

    void brakes(){
        System.out.println("Speed goes on decreasing");    
    }

}
```

In OOP, Object is real car derived from blueprint.After you create object,you can access the door,you can ride it that means you can feel and access attributes and methods of class.

```
public class Car {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Car_Real C1=new Car_Real(); //create object C1 from car    
        C1.runs();    
    }

}
```

And using same class you can create any number of objects as you want.

```
public class Car {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Car_Real C1 = new Car_Real();    
        Car_Real C2 = new Car_Real();    
        C1.runs();    
        C2.brakes(); // create two object C1, C2    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've broken your example up into several chunks.  It seems like all of those methods are supposed to be in the same `Pizza` class.  Is that true?

The methods look like they belong in a command-line application.  If that's the case, you're going to need a `main(...)` method.

```
class Pizza {

    ...the methods you want to test go here...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...your top-level test code goes here...
    }
}
```

First you must compile it.  If you have a command prompt, and you have the JDK installed, you can type this:

```
$ javac Pizza.java
```

Then, if the compiler gives no error messages, you can run it:

```
$ java Pizza
```

See the link provided by @PetterFriberg for more info.

If you want to run it in an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) such as Eclipse or IntelliJ, then that's a whole other question.

Comment: thanks ,,yes all of that methods in the same class pizza but I mean I create the class but how I can create the objects of that class and how I can invoking the instance methods and variables

Comment: To make an instance of a class (a.k.a., an _object_), you use the Java `new` operator.  For example, in your `main()` method, you can say:  `Pizza pizza = new Pizza(...);` where `...` are the actual values that you want to pass in to the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Not bad, but a few pointers:

`switch` statements don't work with Strings, they work with `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int` primitive data types. They also work with enumerated types.

You could set up an enum with the sizes:

```
public enum Size {S,M,L};
```

Then your size field would be of type `Size`:

```
private Size pizzaSize;
```

Make your fields all `private` instead of `public`. That means they cannot be seen from outside the Pizza class. They can be read using getter methods. If they need to be changed, you can provide setter methods too.

Example:

```
public class Pizza {

  //cannot be accessed directly from other classes
  private int cheese;

  //allows other classes to read the value, but not change it
  public int getCheese() {
    return cheese;
  }

  //provide a setter like this if you want other classes to be able to change the value.
  public void setCheese(int cheese) {
    this.cheese = cheese;
  }

}
```

I have omitted the other fields for clarity. Note also that the getter and setter methods match the field name, except with `get` and `set` prepended, and the first letter of the field capitalized. The compiler does not require this, but it is accepted convention and good practice.

Comment: For switch see comment @ Bhargav Modi you can use String on switch with java 7 (I was also still in the world of java 1.4)

Comment: thanks for your help but what did u mean about enumerated types ? i didn't study it yet also the word ( this) in command  this.cheese = cheese

Comment: An enumerated type can only have pre-defined values, for example, the type Size I defined can only have the value S,M or L. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html The keyword `this` simply means this object: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: It is most definitely not "accepted convention" and "good practice". What you have described is the JavaBean specification, which is not required here. Java is verbose enough without adding unnecessary junk out of superstition.